# python postgresql TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, postgresql, typeerror

The command "INSERT into route_list VALUES ('0.0.0.0/0')" works without problems. But the loop doesn't work. What does this error mean? And how to get away from her?

```
data = ['0.0.0.0/0']

for d in data:

  cursor.execute("INSERT into route_list VALUES %s", d)
```

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT into route_list VALUES (%s)", [d])
or
cursor.execute("INSERT into route_list VALUES (%s)", (d,))
or
cursor.execute("INSERT into route_list VALUES ('{0}')".format(d))
```

Comment: Please don't.  Use parameter substitution as described in the [docs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).  Using string formatting for query values is [error-prone and invites SQL injection attacks](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters).

Comment: @snakecharmerb what is wrong in using format(). [This](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters) is not relevant for format()

Comment: @pgyogesh using format (or f-strings) raises exactly the same problems as using %-interpolation or string concatenation: the developer has to be sure to get the variable quoting correct every time or risk introducing bugs or vulnerabilities.  There's no excuse for this when all DB-API libraries do it for free.